# HTML/JavaScript: How to recreate text position/selection inside of a special div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, selection

I'm currently working on a larger project in Django but having quite a hard time when it comes to the JavaScript side of things, as I've just started out with it...

### To break down/simplify the problem:

Inside a special `div` (e.g. `"main-content"`) there will be included some formatted HTML, where the user  selects some text and press a button. After the button is pressed the start and end position of the selection (relative to the `div`, ignoring the HTML tags inside of the `div`, so that the start/end position **must not change when inserting HTML tags**) will be send to the server along some additional information, stored in the database and then will be send via a websocket to different places, where the information will be used to add a `<span ...>...</span>` around the start/end position (based on the same HTML).

First problem: So far I've been able to calculate the relative start/end position of the selection but I have no idea how to recreate the selection after being send over the websocket - is it even possible?
I've looked for JavaScript or jQuery solutions but haven't found anything useful for my case.

Second problem: I want the user only to be able to make a selection in this special div ("main-content") or rather check if the start or end position of the selection is outside of the div. Anyone knows a simple way of doing this?

### Example

HTML (excerpt):

```
...
<div id="controls">
    <h2>Controls</h2>
    some text...
    <input type="button" onclick="alertSelection()" unselectable="on" value="make selection">
</div>
<div id="main-content">
    <h1>Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum <i>dolor</i> sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa <strong>strong</strong>.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
        ...
    </p>
</div>
...
```

JavaScript (excerpt):

```
function getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(element) {
    var start = 0, end = 0;
    var sel, range, priorRange;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        priorRange = range.cloneRange();
        priorRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        priorRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        start = priorRange.toString().length - 1;
        end = start + range.toString().length;
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}

function alertSelection() {
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main-content");
    var sel = getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(mainDiv);
    
    ... sendig to backend stuff ...
}
```

Now if the user makes a selection e.g. "Lorem **ipsum** do" directly at the beginning of the div (effectively containing `<h1>Lorem <b>ipsum</b> do`) and presses the button `alertSelection()` sends start position `0` and end position `14` (along some other information) to the server.

This already works apart from checking if the selection boundries are outside of `"main-content"` (ideas?).

### What still needs to happen:

The server sends the following information via websocket (already working):

- start position: 0
- end position: 14
- style: ...
- additional information: ...

and with this data a `<span style="...">` tag should be added around position `0:14`, so the final result looks like this:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <h1><span style="...">Lorem <b>ipsum</b> do</span>lor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit</h1>
    <p>
        ...
    </p>
</div>
```

Am I even on the right track with this approach or is this impossible or has anyone a simpler solution?

Comment: It's a big confusing trying to figure out what you are asking for, you want to detect where you inserted the span in the DOM? you could do a couple things to find out where it is such as tag it

Comment: @Andrew Sorry if it's confusing, English is not my main language... Basically, I've got a numerical start and end index/position (like when accessing a string in Python) and want to insert the span around the text between these indexes. After inserting, the indexes must not change, so it would be possible to insert multiple span's at once and always get the same result - basically it's like multiple persons having the same text and are told to underline from 1st to 15th character, 45th to 80th character etc.